# No nonzero nilpotent iff the modulus is squarefree

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, integers, nilpotence

This is an exercise from Beachy and Blair: Abstract algebra.

An element $[a]\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ is called nilpotent if $[a]^k=[0]$ for some $k$. Show that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements if and only if $n$ has no factor that is a square (except $1$).

I was thinking like how can we use the fact that $n$ is squarefree (I assume this means that it is a product of different primes)? We maybe could solve some simultaneous congruences in the form
$$
x\equiv a_i \ \bmod p_i \qquad n=\prod p_i,
$$
and show that $a$ has to be congruent with $0$ or something like that, but I failed to do so.

Could you give me some HINTS or intuitions about this?
Anything is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In my limited experience, in most cases, when working with $\mathbb{Z}_n$ or integer numbers, there is no intuition stronger than thinking in terms of prime decomposition.

Comment: [Nilpotent elements in $\Bbb Z_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/749275/721644)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
First of all, remember that $[x] = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if and only if $n \mid x$

So, now suppose that $n$ has a square factor, i.e. $n=k^2m$, what happens to $[km]^2$?

For the other direction, if $n$ is square free then $n=p_1\times \cdots \times p_k$.
Now, if $[r]$ is some element in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ that is non-zero, a prime factor of $n$ must be missing in the prime decomposition of $r$.  What does that tell you about $[r]^k$? Is it possible that $n \mid r^k$?